# Group by date ranges (teradata)

Tags: sql, date, group-by, teradata

I have data like this:

```
Date             User ID
2012-10-11         a
2012-10-11         b
2012-10-12         c
2012-10-12         d 
2012-10-13         e
2012-10-14         b
2012-10-14         e
```

What I want to do is group by the most recent two-day range (in my real query, it will be 7 days) for every day and get the count of distinct user IDs.

For instance, I want the result to look like this:

```
Date             count(distinct userIDs)
2012-10-12         4
2012-10-13         3
2012-10-14         2
```

For instance for 2012-10-12, I get a count of 4 because I have *'a'*, *'b'*, *'c'*, and *'d'*. ' **==>**
*'a'* and *'b'* come from the previous day, and *'c'* and *'d'* come from the same day, 2012-10-12.

Likewise, for 2012-10-13, I am looking at 2012-10-13 and 2012-10-12 and I get *'c'*, *'d'*, and *'e'*.

Date column's data type is date. I am using Teradata.

I've been trying to research it, but couldn't find a straightforward answer that applies to my situation yet. :-/ Sorry if this is a repetition. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I feel sure there is a way to do this using window functions, something like `SELECT date, COUNT(distinct user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` (which is not correct, I tried).  I'll be playing with this myself until I figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you actually need to "multiply" the data because each row can be included in two dates for the final aggregation.

I think the simplest approach for this is a `union all` approach:

```
select date, count(distinct userId)
from ((select date, UserId
       from t
      ) union all
      (select date + 1, UserId     -- combine with yesterday's data
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by date;
```

Because you are dealing with 7 days, here is an alternative approach:

```
select (t.date + n), count(distinct t.UserId)
from t cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
     ) n
group by t.date + n;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this is actually similar to what I ended up doing (except I think it might be more correct to use 'date+1' in the fifth line because for instance, I want to see yesterday's users in today's group)
 I'll provide my approach in a separate post.

Comment: @user1621315 . . . I see exactly what you are saying.  I changed the signs in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely familiar with Teradata syntax, so I'll use redbrick to show you the logic.

```
select date, count(distinct userid) records
from yourtable
where date >= dateadd(day, -2, current_date)
group by date
order by date
```

**Edit starts here**

Upon further review, if you replace

```
where date >= dateadd(day, -2, current_date)
```

with

```
where date >= current_date - 2
```

then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand the logic, but wouldn't this result in only one row (because it filters the dates in the column table by current_date minus 2)?  I need to do this every day that's available in the table.

Comment: @user1621315: The term **group by date** causes teradata (or any DB, since it's "normal" SQL) to count the different (distinct) userid-s on a day by day basis. The user IDs are grouped day by date, then counted.

Comment: @user1621315, perhaps you could elaborate on the term, "most recent two-day range".  That's what inspired by filter on current_date -2.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant most recent relative to all the days I see in the date column.